# Pods_projectA.framework'is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64

Tags: xcode, apple-m1, arm64

I just got an M1 MacBook Pro and am running unit tests on Xcode 13.3 and get the following error:

```
Pods_projectB.framework'is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64
Pods_projectC.framework'is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64
Pods_projectD.framework'is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64
Pods_projectE.framework'is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64
...
```

I've seen a bunch of answers explaining that I can solve the issue by adding `arm64` to `Excluded Architectures`. This does work for me too, but why do I need to this or what can I do to add support for `arm64` (and hence don't need to exclude it?).

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Rosseta' to run Xcode.

[image]

On the next open just clean and build and everything will be fine.